# Uploading more than 50 MB files to S3 bucket directly using javascript

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, file-upload

I am stuck with a problem. I am uploading file to s3 bucket using aws sdk. But for 2-3 mb files it is fine, but while uploading big files I am not able to upload the files. here is my JS code :

```
<script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.283.1.min.js"></script>
AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId : 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    secretAccessKey : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
});
AWS.config.region = 'us-west-1';
$("#uploadForm").submit(function () {
        $("#progress").show();
        var bucket = new AWS.S3({params: {Bucket: 'bucketname', apiVersion: '2006-03-01'}});
        var uploadFiles = $('#upFile')[0];
        var upFile = uploadFiles.files[0];
        if (upFile) {
            var uploadParams = {Key: 'podcats/' + (Date.now()) + '/' + upFile.name, ContentType: upFile.type, Body: stream, ACL: 'public-read'};
            bucket.upload(uploadParams).on('httpUploadProgress', function (evt) {
bucket.upload(uploadParams).on('httpUploadProgress', function (evt) {
                //console.log("File Uploading: " + parseInt((evt.loaded * 100) / evt.total)+'%');
            }).send(function (err, data) {
                console.log(data);
            });;
        }
        return false;
    })
```

;

Please help me to resolve the issue. I tried and made more R&D but did not find any solutions. please note : i am using PHP as a server side programming, but not used to communicate with s3.

Answer (score 0):

1. Rather than single upload, can you please try multi-part upload and see if any same error is coming or not. Please refer to this URL: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#createMultipartUpload-property
2. Try to use the latest version of node js to check if the same error is coming or not/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not using node js to implement that. You mean I should upload the file to server and then upload the file from server side script to s3.

Comment: please refer this URL . This might be helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks subhadeep. but do i need to login everytime with that user?

Comment: Hi, are you talking about the AWS security credentials which is needed to upload file to S3 bucket. You can hard  code that in your script or read that from your environment file but this might not considered as best practise.  You can create IAM role,and create a policy to assign permission on S3 bucket using that IAM role.